Can't run python script from terminal but can from PyCharm: ModuleNotFoundError
I have never run python from a terminal before so I don't know what is involved, I have always run my project from PyCharm. My project runs fine from PyCharm. I am running on Linux. My file structure is as follows:
BackTesting        - This is my project
    BackTestPkg    - One of my packages
        __init__py
        Parameters.py
        ...
    MAX1           - My main development
        MAX1_Controller.py
        MAX1_Main.py
        ...
    TradingPkg     - My other package
        __init__.py
        PlatformLib.py
        ...

MAX1_Controller.py calls MAX1_Main.py, and both call modules in both BackTestPkg and TradingPkg packages, which in turn call other modules in these 2 packages.
When I perform the following at the linux terminal:
/data/stuart/Projects/Python/Env/bin/python /data/stuart/Projects/Python/BackTesting/MAX1/MAX1_Controller.py 'EpicConfigs.csv' 'MAX1.param'

I get the following terminal error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/BackTesting/MAX1/MAX1_Controller.py", line 10, in <module>
    import MAX1_Main as main
  File "/data/stuart/Projects/Python/BackTesting/MAX1/MAX1_Main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import TradingPkg.PlatformLib as pl
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'TradingPkg'

I have never worked with python outside PyCharm so I don't know what I can try. Other posts I looked at looked complicated and overkill for what I am sure is a simple solution. Can anybody point me in the right direction please.
Regards, StuartM

What is your current working directory when you run on the command line vs in your IDE? In your terminal, have you activated your environment?

Have you added the correct paths to your PYTHONPATH when you try to run the script from the terminal?

Most probably it's you vnev.

the PWD is in the terminal is in my 'BackTesting' folder - at the same as BackTestPkg and TradingPkg. My ENV folder is at the same level as 'BackTesting'. I have tried activating the venv with 'source ./ENV/bin/activate'.

I ran 'export PYTHONPATH="BackTestPkg"' from my BackTesting folder, but I am still getting errors relation to my 2 local packages

I would define a requirements.txt file with what packages you want and versions. Then activate a virtual environment and install that requirement.txt file and that should fix the 'No module named' error.

Making Virtual Environment in root directory
python3 -m venv venv

Activate Virtual Environment on macOS/Linux:
source venv/bin/activate
On windows
venv\Scripts\activate

With the virtual Environment installed, install required packages
pip install -r requirements.txt

Run your python project like normal



I created a requirements.txt file and added my 2 local packages to the end, but I don'y have any version numbers for them - what should I use? As a resuly when I run 'pip install -r requirements.txt' I get message: "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement BackTestPkg (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for BackTestPkg"

I added 'BackTestPkg' and 'TradingPkg' to the end of the requirements.txt that PyCharm created. Is a version mandatory? I presume so from the error I get. But what should I use for a local/private package?

I investigated and it turns out that specifying a version is not a requirement. All you have to do is enter the name of the package, which is what I have done. So why the error when I install the requirements.txt?

Anybody? Please.

First install the package using pip install yourpkgname,
Then you can run your code from terminal
Note: check the version of pip , if upgrade available then first upgrade pip using
pip install --upgrade pip
and then use pip to install your pkg.
Sometime because of older version of pip even after doing the installation of pkg this 'module not found' error come

When I run ../Env/bin/pip install ./TradingPkg from in my BackTesting folder (in the terminal) I get the message "ERROR: Directory './TradingPkg' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found."

I upgraded pip from version 24.0 to 24.2 but didn't seem to make any difference
